# Can't read local .parquet file with Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

there! I'm newer in Apache Spark and I need a help.
Trying to read local .parquet file with local Spark context:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("parquetUtility")
            .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().parquet("/Users/file.parquet");
```

And I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null" error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:4.4]
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1].....
```

I try to read .json file and it works! But it doesn't work with my .parquet.
Parquet file I created with Spark parquet writer.

Here is my Spark configuration:

```
@Bean
@Profile("local")
public SparkConf sparkConf(){
    return new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local[*]")
            .set("spark.executor.memory", "6G")
            .set("spark.driver.memory", "6G")
            .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10")
            .setAppName("parquetUtility");
}
```

Thanks for your help)

UPDATE: this is works on Windows & Debian OS, but it's don't work on my Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20364

Comment: What version of java are you using ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala java 8 and spark core 2.3.1

Comment: I was getting similar errors because I was using Java 9, and downgrading to Java 8 worked for me.

Comment: @KyleBarron, your answer seems to be correct. Please post it.